# How does Dedekind axiom imply continuity axiom

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers, axioms

I am trying to understand a theorem that proves that the supremum axiom, Dedekind axiom, and continuity axiom are all equivalent. I have trouble understanding one point in the proof that DED implies CON. So for the definition, the book I'm using defines the following:

$(1)$ Let X be an ordered set. The pair $(D_1, D_2)$ of subsets $D_1, D_2 \subset X$ is called a Dedekind cut if it has the following properties:
$D_1 \cup D_2 = X\tag{A}$
$D_1 \neq \emptyset, \ D_2 \neq \emptyset\tag{B}$
$\delta_1 \in D_1 \wedge \delta_2 \in D_2 \implies \delta_1 < \delta_2\tag{C}$

The axioms are stated as follows:

(DED) If $D_1$, $D_2$ $\subset \mathbb{R}$ are such that $(D_1, D_2)$ is a Dedekind cut then there exists a least upper bound sup $D_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ of the set $D_1$.

(CON) Let $T$ and $S$ be two nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with the property:
$(\forall t\in T)(\forall s\in S) t\leq s$. Then there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\forall t\in T)(\forall s\in S)t\leq c \leq s$.

Finally, the proof (or the part that is weird) goes as follows (keep in mind the implication we are trying to prove, namely DED $\implies$ CON):

Suppose DED holds and let $T, S$ be sets with the property from CON. Let $D_1 = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\rvert (\forall s\in S)x<s \}$ and $D_2 = \mathbb{R}\setminus D_1$. Then, $(D_1, D_2)$ is a Dedekind cut. To prove this, first note that $(A)$ holds from the definition of sets $D_1, D_2$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and
$$
T_{\epsilon} := \{t-\epsilon\lvert t\in T\}
$$

Obiously $S\subset D_2$ and $T_\epsilon \subset D_1$, since by assumption of CON, $T$ and $S$ are nonempty we proved (B). If $\delta_1 \in D_1$, then $\delta_1<s$ for all $s\in S$. Let:
$$
\delta_2\in D_2.
$$
If it were to be $\delta_2 \leq \delta_1$, then it would imply $\delta_2 < s$ for all $s\in S$. By definition of $D_1$ this would yield $\delta_2 \in D_1$,which together with $\delta_2\in D_2$ and (C) gives the contradiction $\delta_2<\delta_2$. Thus $(D_1, D_2)$ is a Dedekind cut.....(he goes on to prove the rest but I understand that part)

The only problem I have is with the very last bit. How do we suppose (C)? Aren't we trying to prove (C)? If someone can clarify the argument above or suggest an improvement I would be very grateful.

Comment: It does not assume that (C) is true. It assumes that $\delta_1\in D_1$ and that $\delta_2\in D_2$. Then it goes on to prove that $\delta_2\not \leq \delta_1$ using a contradiction. Mind that (C) is an if-then property/ statement so we construct the setting of the if-part and prove that the implication given is **always** true. Hence conclude that (C) is true.